# Tensorflow Estimators: what's the difference between serving_input_fn and input_fn

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

It seems redundant to me to define twice the input function for the model and exporter. Why don't just use a unique input function in both the definition and the exporter

For example, for the MNIST images example where the input is an image of 28x28x1, the `input_fn` and `serving_input_fn` are as follow.

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={INPUT_FEATURE: train_data},
    y=train_labels,
    batch_size=100,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
```

.

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  inputs = {
    INPUT_FEATURE: tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1]),
  }
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)
```

.

```
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=FLAGS.steps)
classifier.export_savedmodel(DIR_MODEL,
        serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

At the end both define a dict {INPUT_FEATURE: image}

Answer (score 1):

`serving_input_fn` is necessary when you want to make prediction which is used to define the input dtype with `tf.placeholder`. `input_fn` will return a dataset of source and target sequences for training which is used to train.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510264/in-tensorflow-for-serving-a-model-what-does-the-serving-input-function-supposed) be helpful.